# How to listen to a pair of both { websocket + zmq broker } in a node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, zeromq

I have a simple node.js server that is using a websocket to get market data from an exchange and using a ZeroMQ router socket to receive commands from a GUI front end.

I'm a little lost on how to get both of these playing nice each with the other and not have one block the other.

Here's one thing I've tried:

```
var main = function() {
    console.log(Date().toString());
    try {
        var broker = zmq.socket('router');
        broker.bindSync('tcp://*:5672');

        client.on('connect', function(connection: any) {
            console.log('Connected to Server...');

            connection.on('message', function(message: any) {
                if(message.type === 'utf8') {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
                    console.log(obj);
                    publisher.send(message.utf8Data);
                }
            });

            function send(message: any) {
                if (connection.connected) {
                    connection.sendUTF(message);
                }
            }

            //const quoteTokenInfo = await zeroEx.tokenRegistry.getTokenBySymbolIfExistsAsync("WETH");
            //const baseTokenInfo = await zeroEx.tokenRegistry.getTokenBySymbolIfExistsAsync("ZRX");

            send(`{
            "type": "subscribe",
            "channel": "orderbook",
            "requestId": 1,
            "payload": {
                "baseTokenAddress": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
                "quoteTokenAddress": "0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498",
                "snapshot": true,
                "limit": 4
            }
            }`);
        });

        client.on('message', function(message: any) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            console.log(obj);
        });

        client.onmessage = function(message: any) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            console.log(obj);
        };

        broker.on('message', function () {
            var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
            var identity = args[0]

            if (args.length < 2) {
                broker.send([identity, 'ERROR']);
                    return;
            }
            var message = args[1].toString('utf8');
            if(args.length > 3) {
                var quote = args[2].toString('utf8');
                var base = args[3].toString('utf8');
            }

            if(message === 'TopOfBook') {
                getTopOfBook(quote, base).then((result) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'TopOfBook', result])
                }, (err) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'ERROR']
                )}).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            } else if(message === 'NewBid') {
                var size = args[4].toString('utf8');
                var rate = args[5].toString('utf8');
                rate = parseFloat(rate);
                rate.toFixed(8);
                placeBid(quote, base, size, rate).then((result) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'SUCCESS'])
                }, (err) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'FAILURE']
                )}).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            } else if(message === 'NewOffer') {
                var size = args[4].toString('utf8');
                var rate = args[5].toString('utf8');
                rate = parseFloat(rate);
                rate.toFixed(8);
                placeOffer(quote, base, size, rate).then((result) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'SUCCESS'])
                }, (err) => {
                    broker.send([identity, 'FAILURE']
                )}).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I've also tried having the **`client.on( 'connect', ... )`** function outside of `main(){...}`. The above code does not print any messages from the websocket aside from the initial connection. If I have it outside of `main(){...}`, it will print the first snapshot and print no others.

I'm also blurry on how javascript will handle messages based on how the code is organised. For example, is it ok to have a `main(){...}` function with the **`broker.on()`** handlers in it, while having a **`client.on()`** handler outside of that `main()` function? Or will one block the other?

Also regarding using the client websocket, what's the difference between having
a **`connection.on( 'message', ... )`**
vs having
a **`client.onmessage( ... )`**.

Any clarity is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### A short version:

Designer's responsibility is to always avoid any kind of blocking, the more under a shared, common event-loop system.

---

### Moving things outside the `main()` scope:

This is a point I will rather leave for javascript evangelisators, the core problem is in proper understanding the concept of blocking and event-loop and handlers.

---

### ZeroMQ part:

ZeroMQ is a great tool, yet one will benefit most, if diving more into the systematic view onto distributed-systems design best practices, instead of "just copy" a few SLOC-s. Distributed systems enter one into a new realm, where a "pure"-[SERIAL] code execution does not work. There is a great book from Pieter Hintjens, I advise all people, who decided to go into the domain of distributed-systems design to read, it is definitely worth time and efforts.

So, using **`.bind()`** instead of **`.bindSync()`** seems to be the first thing to review.

Next, always test one event-loop component before adding another one, so as to isolate the root cause of the problem. Having assembled a hairball of event-handlers inside one common eventloop will efficiently prevent you from debugging yet untested components and things can die in silence of turn the code wreck havoc, without one's knowledge where and why. This comes triple true, if having multi-layered event-loops that chase the common systems resources concurrently.

Asking others to repair one's lack of proper system analysis efforts and a lack of due proper design care is possible, but it is neither fair the less a sustainable professional practice.

```
var main = function() {
 /*.log()--------------------------------------------------------*/ console.log( Date().toString() );
    try {
        var broker = zmq.socket( 'router' );
            broker.bindSync( 'tcp://*:5672' );
         // broker.bind(     'tcp://*:5672' ); // ------------------ NEVER BLOCK 
        
        client.on( 'connect',
                    function( connection: any ) {
                           /*.log()------------------------------*/ console.log( 'Connected to Server...' );
                              connection.on( 'message',
                                              function( message: any ) {
                                                        if (  message.type === 'utf8' ) {
                                                            var obj = JSON.parse( message.utf8Data );
                                                         /*.log()*/ console.log( obj );
                                                            publisher.send( message.utf8Data );
                                                        }
                                              }
                              );
                            // ------------------------------------------------
                              function send( message: any ) {
                                             if ( connection.connected ) {
                                                  connection.sendUTF( message );
                                             }
                              }
                              
                           // const quoteTokenInfo = await zeroEx.tokenRegistry.getTokenBySymbolIfExistsAsync( "WETH" );
                           // const baseTokenInfo  = await zeroEx.tokenRegistry.getTokenBySymbolIfExistsAsync( "ZRX" );
                              
                              send( `{ "type":      "subscribe",
                                       "channel":   "orderbook",
                                       "requestId":  1,
                                       "payload": { "baseTokenAddress":  "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
                                                    "quoteTokenAddress": "0xe41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498",
                                                    "snapshot":           true,
                                                    "limit":              4
                                        }
                                       }`
                                   );
                    }
        );            
        client.on( 'message',
                    function( message: any ) {
                              var obj = JSON.parse( message.utf8Data );
                           /*.log()------------------------------*/ console.log( obj );
                    }
        );
        client.onmessage = function( message: any ) {
                                     var obj = JSON.parse( message.utf8Data );
                                  /*.log()-----------------------*/ console.log( obj );
                           };
        
        broker.on( 'message',
                    function () {
                              var args     = Array.apply( null, arguments );
                              var identity = args[0]
                              
                              if (  args.length <  2 ) {
                                    broker.send( [ identity,
                                                  'ERROR'
                                                   ]
                                                 );
                                    return; // ------------------------------------------^ JIT/RET
                              }
                              var message = args[1].toString( 'utf8' );
                              if (  args.length >  3 ) {
                                    var quote = args[2].toString( 'utf8' );
                                    var base  = args[3].toString( 'utf8' );
                              }
                              
                              if (         message === 'TopOfBook' ) {
                                    getTopOfBook( quote, base ).then( ( result ) => {
                                        broker.send( [ identity,
                                                      'TopOfBook',
                                                       result
                                                       ]
                                                     )
                                    }, ( err ) => {
                                        broker.send( [ identity,
                                                      'ERROR'
                                                       ]
                                                     )
                                    } ).catch( ( error ) => {
                                     /*.LOG:---------------------*/ console.log( error );
                                    } );
                              } else if (  message === 'NewBid' ) {
                                    var size = args[4].toString( 'utf8' );
                                    var rate = args[5].toString( 'utf8' );
                                        rate = parseFloat( rate );
                                        rate.toFixed( 8 );
                                    placeBid( quote, base, size, rate ).then( ( result ) => {
                                        broker.send( [ identity,
                                                      'SUCCESS'
                                                       ]
                                                     )
                                    }, ( err ) => {
                                        broker.send( [ identity,
                                                      'FAILURE'
                                                       ]
                                                     )
                                    } ).catch( ( error ) => {
                                     /*.LOG:---------------------*/ console.log( error );
                                    } );
                              } else if (  message === 'NewOffer' ) {
                                   var size = args[4].toString( 'utf8' );
                                   var rate = args[5].toString( 'utf8' );
                                       rate = parseFloat( rate );
                                       rate.toFixed( 8 );
                                   placeOffer( quote, base, size, rate ).then( ( result ) => {
                                       broker.send( [ identity,
                                                     'SUCCESS'
                                                      ]
                                                    )
                                   }, ( err ) => {
                                       broker.send( [ identity,
                                                     'FAILURE'
                                                      ]
                                                    )
                                   } ).catch( ( error ) => {
                                    /*.LOG:----------------------*/ console.log( error );
                                   } );
                              }
                    }
        )
    }
    catch ( err ) {
     /*.LOG:-----------------------------------------------------*/ console.log( err );
    }
}
```